# Fit text in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a bulk of text in a string array which has to be placed in a TextView so that there should not be any scroll bar and the text has to fit exactly in the screen. I want to keep adding the text to textview until the screen gets filled and the remaining text has to be displayed in the next page and so on.

I thought of doing that by finding the height of the textview when it is updated but it was helpless!!

Though I have searched many websites I could not find a solution for that !!

Is it possible to acheive such criteria ?

Forgive if there are any errors in the above !!

Thanks,

Siva Kumar

Comment: Have you tried this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds/5535672#5535672

Answer (score 0):

From anticafe (comment)
[Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds/5535672#5535672)

Great subclass of textview providing resizing functions.